# Can't connect to wireless, broadcom doesn't work

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I have broadcom drivers but it doesn't work, when I hit apply change noething happens.
I have only WIFI and can't connect to networks.
Output of: `lspci -vnn | grep Network` :

```
Network controlles [0280]: Broadcam Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.2

Comment: how did you install the drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the drivers from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/bcmwl-kernel-source)

You will have to select amd64 for a 64 bit install or i386 for a 32 bit install and then select a mirror site.  If you are unsure if you have 32 or 64 bit, open a terminal window (CTRL + t) and enter `arch`, x86_64 = 64 bit.  Then double click on the downloaded file to install.

I checked just a few days ago and the version of bcmwl-kernel-source on the Ubuntu 14.04.2 installation ISO was the incorrect version for kernel 3.16 and if this fixes your problem, feel free to click "This bug affects...does this bug affect you" on this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1432444)